# Calculating probability of a female US president

Tags: forecasting, elections

What solid evidence could we use to assess the chances of a woman being elected in the next US presidential election 2020?

The last 45 US presidents were male. That's a hit rate of 100%. Intuitively though, I have a feeling that it could happen.

Comment: Let $Fem20$ be the event that a female becomes president in 2020. Let $Party20_i$ be the event that party $i$'s candidate is elected. Let $FemNom_j$ be the event that party $j$ nominates a female standard bearer. Then $P(Fem20)=\sum_{i,j} P(Fem20, Party20_i,FemNom_j) = \sum P(Fem20| Party20_i) P(Party20_i|FemNom_j) P(FemNom_j) $

Comment: (continued). We can add additional conditionals, the event that a popular recent VP throws his hat into the ring, and whether https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Octopus had politically-minded progeny. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because statistics is not applicable for this kind of problem.

Comment: @user158565: at least we could get an answer about why stats can't be applied to this kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of question you might want to ask FiveThirtyEight.com. I'm not a political scientist, but from casual observation, they appear to combine traditional statistics and what I believe is a microsimulation model to answer this type of question. If @user54285 is saying that we don't know **anything** about the odds involved, I'll disagree. We know something. However, this far out from the Presidential election, we know very little, and our estimates of the probability of events happening will definitely change, as he/she is correct to observe.

There are betting markets for all sorts of things, and these could give us a plausible guess at the probability of one of the female Democratic Presidential hopefuls winning the nomination. You could also observe current polling of the candidates and make a prediction based on that. The thing is, right now, your data will not be that good, and the betting markets and polls will probably fluctuate a lot. For example, a lot of potential primary voters may not have formed opinions on all candidates, or even heard of them - do you know who's [Peter Buttigieg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Buttigieg), for example, and can you even pronounce his name?

The Republican primary should be simpler. We can simply assume that the incumbent will win. I suspect that FiveThirtyEight may explicitly model the probability of a successful primary challenge. If they do, I bet the probability of this happening  will be very small, but not zero.

Once you had the probability that a woman wins the Democratic nomination, you need some sort of model to predict the probability of the Democrats winning the election. To the best of my knowledge, existing models for that sort of thing would account for national polling averages, plus economic fundamentals, plus the President's popularity rating, plus the fact that the current President is an incumbent, which is normally a significant advantage. The problem there is that all these things save for incumbency could change a lot between now and the election. You could wait until after the Democratic primary, then start building the model above, of course. It's just a regression model. I don't know if it's a linear model, or if it's a fractional logistic model. I think that FiveThirtyEight uses things like lowess smoothing for the polling average.

Moreover, FiveThirtyEight models elections at the state level using state-level polling. To my recollection, they then run a state-level microsimulation, which will spit out the probability of each side winning the election, plus a distribution of the magnitude of the Electoral College margin (plus a lot of other things, actually, e.g. races for each state's open House and Senate seats plus governorship). If you had the time and you wanted to be thorough, you could also do this, or you could just rely on national average polling and call it close enough.

So, what the heck does this have to do with Cross Validated? Well, hopefully the token references to statistical techniques I made will help this question qualify for not being deleted. More seriously, simulation or simulation-like techniques (I'm thinking of Markov models for the latter) can be extremely useful tools for inference. For example, in my real line of work, some people funded by the Agency for Healthcare Research and Quality in the US did a systematic literature review and meta-analysis on the [efficacy of post-hospital transitional care programs for heart failure patients](https://effectivehealthcare.ahrq.gov/topics/heart-failure-transition-care/policymaker). (Disclosure: AHRQ funded the first year in my PhD program.) We can say something about how much the average such program reduces readmission to hospital or mortality within 6 months after an initial admission.

However, what if we wanted to make some inference about cost reductions, or what if we wanted to know what happens over a longer time period? We don't know that from the experiments that were reviewed. We could, however, use Markov modeling or simulation to make some inference about that.

Comment: I actually am saying that past probabilities/events likely tell you little because the reality is changing making past events of limited value. No one thought Trump would win because the models that predicted elections failed to adjust to these type of changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the practical problem with answering this question is that you would have to know the underlying distribution to do this and we don't. I am not sure social distributions can be generated with any certainty (and will change rapidly).

In time series they speak of structural breaks. When reality changes and past events mean little to judge future ones. That is the reality I think in this issue.